# Change location, prevent redirect

Tags: jquery, html, href

I have a popup which opens when you click on a link. I want it behave like Facebook Images or Pinterest popups where the popup opens, and the URL changes but there's no redirect.

My code is this :

```
<a href="/movies.jsp?id=123123" class="item-img">
    <img src="/images/123123.jpg" />
</a>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.item-img', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //code for popup
});
</script>
```

`preventDefault` helps prevent the redirect but the url doesnt change.  (Using Jquery)

How do I achieve the desired result ?

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the url...you will get a redirect. Except if you are implementing a Single Page Application (SPA) which uses the hash to change the url (which does not cause a redirect).

Comment: Any idea how they do it for FB, Pinterest ? I notice an `<a>` tag with an href in both those sites, that just comes up without a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to open a javascript popup window:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item-img', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, "self", 'width=200, height=300');
});
```

Comment: Jai, I am using a plugin (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) for popup, loading the content via ajax. Is there anyway I can just change the url when the popup is opened?

Comment: well thats ajax call which is required to do such work, you have to store the `old url` in a var when you click on the image link and then you can change the url in the browser window by passing the clicked image url and when you close the popup replace the old url in the window.

Answer (score 0):

I found something here that can help you [Popups like coderwall or facebook (url change but no redirect)](https://coderwall.com/p/0j1spw)

I think is all about pushing an entry into the history stack and displaying popup

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a[rel=popup_link]").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(e.target).attr("href");
    //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'

    if(url != window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:url},'',url) ;
    }
    $.colorbox({
      inline: true,
      href: "<your content>",
      open: true
    });
 });
});
```

[Colorbox plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

**Edit:** 
I've tested it on IE only

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud! But this works only in IE10 or above coz of HTML5. Any idea how to replicate in browsers below that?